# How to hide/show a text-box base on other text-box in Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-4

**Goal**

- **show** `email confirm` when a user start editing the email section.
- **hide** the `email confirm` text-box if the user doesn't touch it.
- Don't do anything if the user only edit the username part.

**Edit Form**

- username* __________________________
- email*    __________________________
- email confirm* _____________________

HTML/BLADE

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required ">Username </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group float-label-control ">


            {{ Form::text('username',  isset($user->username) ? $user->username : '' , array('id'=>'form-field-icon-2')); }}

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required ">Email </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group float-label-control ">


            {{ Form::text('email', isset($user->email ) ? $user->email  : '' , array('id'=>'form-field-icon-2')); }}

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: searching for jquery .keyup .keydown and how to use it

Comment: Can you show me your current HTML code if you have any?

Comment: In the HTML/Blade section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<label> Username </label><br>
<input type="text" name="username"><br>

<label> Email </label><br>    
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>

<label id="l-email-conf" > Email Confirm </label><br> 
<input type="text" name="email_confirm" disabled="disabled" id="email-conf">
```

JS

```
$('#l-email-conf').hide();
$('#email-conf').hide();

$('#email').on('input', function (event) {
  var text = $(this).val();

  if (text === '') { // If email is empty
    $('#email-conf').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#email-conf').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#email-conf').show();
      $('#l-email-conf').show();
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt6qstmk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Say this is your HTML -

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="text" name="email_confirm" disabled="disabled" id="email-conf">

<script>
// Use jQuery event handlers
$('#email').on('input', function (event) {
  var text = $(this).val();

  if (text === '') { // If email is empty
    $('#email-conf').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#email-conf').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaustv_datta/mt6qstmk/2/)

**P.S.** - U can toggle hide/show instead of disabling also.

Comment: It doesn't work see http://jsfiddle.net/mt6qstmk/ , the Email Confirm text-box stay disable at all time. Please kindly clarify.

Comment: @evoque2015 looks like I'm late :( Updated the answer. Had to use .val() instead of .text()

Answer (score 1):

Inline javascript could be an elegant solution if you don't want to write a function. 
onkeyup and onkeydown events will do the job and you don't need jQuery

```
<form>
   <p>
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onkeyup="this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';" onkeydown="this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';"/>
   </p>
   <p id="confirm-email">
     <label for="confirm">Confirm email</label>
     <input type="text" name="confirm" id="confirm"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#confirm-email {
    display: none;
}
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8doeavv/)

Comment: It's cool that we can do this inline. According to your jsFiddle, when I Edit something on the Email, I saw a new box , but as soon as I clicked on it,  it's disappear on me. Can you please check that ? Thanks

Comment: Work great. Thanks for fixing it for me.